# Using SED to replace specific patterns found within parentheses?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I'm having a bit of a problem with this...
I'm trying to use Bash scripting (Sed, in particular) to process the following text. Other methods are welcome, of course! But I'm hoping it could be a Bash solution...

Tricky input:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."E"|"F"
```

Desired output:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."ABC".("e"|"f")."EF"
```

Mainly, I think what I want to do is replace the strings `"|"` with nothing, but limit the scope of change outside of any existing text in parentheses.

The problems gets more crazy with different forms of text inputs I have with the dataset that I have. As in, the combination of blocks (delimited by `.`) with parentheses and non-parenthesese is varied.

Thanks in advance.

---

Something I've tried with SED:

```
gsed -E "s/(\.\"[[:graph:]]+)\"\|\"/\1/g" input.txt
```

output i get is:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."EF"
```

Looks like I'm only getting the partially desired output...only targeting a limited scope...

Comment: Decide on the order of operations and it may be solvable. Are the parentheses protecting what's contained within or why wouldn't this collapse into "ABC", "ABC", "EF"?

Comment: Hello, not sure what you mean by "why wouldn't this collapse into...". The goal is to prevent the replacement of `"|"` that exist in parens, while doing so for the text that isn't in parens. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that answered my question: "_Are the parentheses protecting what's contained within_". Make a table of the order of operations as you see them and work it out with a pen and paper. If you can't make that work, trying to program it will be problematic.

Comment: for sake of discussion ... groups of characters are separated by a period (`.`); are all odd-numbered fields wrapped in parens? and even-numbered fields have no parens?  you've mentioned `sed` ... please update the question with what `sed` commands you've tried and the (wrong) results they generated

Comment: the groups of characters with parens can appear in various places, not just in odd-numbered fields...entirely optional, and the total number of "fields" isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions/understandings:

- fields are separated by periods
- fields wrapped in parens are to be left alone
- all other fields have leading/trailing double quotes while all other double quotes, as well as pipes, are to be removed

Sample data:

```
$ cat pipes.dat
("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."E"|"F"
"j"|"K"|"L"."m"|"n"|"o"|"p".("x"|"y"|"z")
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="." }                                      # define input/output field separator as a period

      { printf "############\nbefore: %s\n",$0            # print a record separator and the current input line;
                                                          # solely for display purposes; this line can
                                                          # be removed/commented-out once logic is verified

        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)                             # loop through fields
            if ( $i !~ "^[(].*[)]$" )                     # if field does not start/end with parens then ...
                $i="\"" gensub(/"|\|/,"","g",$i) "\""     # replace field with a new double quote (+) modified string
                                                          # whereby all double quotes and pipes are removed (+)
                                                          # a new ending double quote

        printf "after : %s\n",$0                          # print the newly modified line;
                                                          # can be replaced with "print" once logic is verified
      }
' pipes.dat                                               # read data from file; to read from a variable remove this line and ...
#' <<< "${variable_name}"                                 # uncomment this line
```

The above generates:

```
############
before: ("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."E"|"F"
after : ("a"|"b"|"c")."ABC".("e"|"f")."EF"
############
before: "j"|"K"|"L"."m"|"n"|"o"|"p".("x"|"y"|"z")
after : "jKL"."mnop".("x"|"y"|"z")
```

---

After removing comments and making the `printf` changes:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="." }
      { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            if ( $i !~ "^[(].*[)]$" )
                $i="\"" gensub(/"|\|/,"","g",$i) "\"" 
        print
      }
' pipes.dat
```

Which generates:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."ABC".("e"|"f")."EF"
"jKL"."mnop".("x"|"y"|"z")
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you for this answer. I'll do some studying on AWK.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "."}                     # use "." as a field separator
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                 # loop over the fields
        if ($i !~ "^\\(.+\\)$") {               # if the fields is not enclosed with "(" and ")"
            gsub("\"\\|\"", "", $i)             # then remove "|"s
        }
    }
    print
}' <<< '("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."E"|"F"'
```

Output:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."ABC".("e"|"f")."EF"
```

**[Explanations]**

- The `BEGIN {}` block is executed just once before processing the input
  file. It is useful to initialize variables.
- As the awk variable `FS` is assigned to ".",
  the input line(s) are automatically
  split on ".". Then `$1` is assigned to the 1st field `("a"|"b"|"c")`,
  `$2` is assigned to the 2nd `"A"|"B"|"C"` .. and so on. The awk variable
  `NF` is set to the number of fields (4 in this example).
- The for loop `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)` iterates over the fields to
  examine `$1`, `$2`, ... in turn.
- The regex `"^\\(.+\\)$"` matches if the variable `$i`,
  the i'th field value, starts with `(` and ends with `)`.
  The operator `!~` negates the matching result then the `if` condition
  meets for the fields which are not enclosed with parens such as `"A"|"B"|"C"`.
- The function `gsub("\"\\|\"", "", $i)` removes the substring `"|"`
  as many as possible out of `$i`. The character `"` must be escaped with
  `\` and `|` must be escaped with `\\`.  It may make the code obscured
  and less readable.
- The final `print` is a shorthand of `print $0` which print the modified
  line composed of the fields: $1, $2, ... $4 by delimiting with `OFS`,
  which is also assigned to ".".

Comment: This is great. Thank you for this answer. I'll do some studying on AWK.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added some explanations of the code hopefully to help you study.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done with GNU sed

Input file content

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."A"|"B"|"C".("e"|"f")."E"|"F"
"j"|"K"|"L"."m"|"n"|"o"|"p".("x"|"y"|"z")
```

GNU sed command:

```
sed -znr ':-A s/([\)][^\|]+)\"\|\"(.*[\(])/\1\2/;t-A;p;q' file
```

Output:

```
("a"|"b"|"c")."ABC".("e"|"f")."EF"
"jKL"."mnop".("x"|"y"|"z")
```